# Magnetic timeline in Final Cut Pro X optional?

Tags: imovie, final-cut-pro

Is the magnetic timeline on Final Cut Pro X optional? I see the advantages of the magnetic timeline, but nonetheless still prefer dedicated layers as it gives me a much greater sense of control of specific kinds of resources. I have been considering Final Cut Pro X but if the magnetic timeline is imposed upon its users, or if it is optional but there are no significant layer controls when magnetic timeline is disabled such as hide/mute, etc., it's a complete showstopper for me. I'm coming from Sony Vegas Platinum HD 10 to which I migrated from iMovie, and right now Final Cut Pro X looks like going back to iMovie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not optional. However, in use, I think you'll adjust and have the same sense of control very quickly. Have a look at the various online tutorials. I found this one exceptionally helpful http://www.izzyvideo.com/final-cut-pro-x-tutorial/ Also spend a little time with it and you'll soon see it's not anything like iMovie.

Comment: Yeah I don't see myself "spending a little time with it" when there is no trial version download. There's very little in the link you provided that suggests a different workflow than my existing iMovie workflow (note that I inverted the timeline and events to match the Pro X timeline workflow). I've definitely decided against buying this as channel-oriented layer control is simply not optional and it's ridiculous of Apple to attempt to deprecate it. I prefer to group specific layers and isolate them, etc. Pro X has an interesting workflow but it's simply not practical for everything.

Comment: @stimpy77 I agree it should be optional, but after a few months of hating the software now I understand intuitively how to use it. It makes sense but it will take a few bumps in the head before you grasp the interface. Another issue is the lack of redundancy, for instance, to reconnect media you won't find the option right-clicking on a given clip, you MUST select the clips first and then go to "File", "Relink", etc. But you are indeed able to create "parallel timelines" which can behave as layers, you can also use "roles" to control specific audio clips, even if they are randomly scattered.